# Flask Application on Azure App Service throwing "405 Method Not Allowed" error

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have a simple Flask app as shown below which is modularized using Flask Blueprint functionality. On local deployment & testing Flask App is running without any issue, I can see the expected output but when the app is deployed on the Azure App service and the request is sent from either Postman or Python then I am getting the below error. Can anyone tell me what I am missing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

Below are relevant data

**App structure**

```
/root
 |- app.py
 |- routes
 |  |- test.py
 |- send_request.py
 |- requirements.txt
```

**test.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify

route = Blueprint("test", __name__, url_prefix="/test")

@route.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def test():
   data = request.json["test"]
   print(data)
   return jsonify(data)
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from routes import test

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(test.route)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

**send_request.py**

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://<app>.azurewebsites.net/test"

payload = json.dumps({
  "test": "Hello World!"
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: This may not be the cause of the error, but in `send_request.py`, the request is sending a content-type=application/json header, but the request is not actually sending json...

Comment: Won't the URL you're trying to hit have a trailing `/`? i.e. your URL should be: `"https://<app>.azurewebsites.net/test/"`

Comment: @PGHE Thanks adding trailing `/` in the url fixed the issue, could you please put this as answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, these errors occur either when the URL is not correctly given or when the server does not support the HTTP method used in the request. It means that, the method used in the request isn't permitted for the URL you've requested.

If we consider the current issue of yours, the web app URL is incorrect as pointed out by @PGHE. Because

`https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/xxxx` ≠ `https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/xxxx/`.

*A trailing slash will be handled as a separate URL in all cases except the one just after the root domain. And the response, request body looks good.*

In the portal, the web app deployments URL will be in the below shown format. However, while deploying from local, we must include `"/"` at the end of the app domain URL.

[image]

My *requirements.txt:*

```py
requests==2.18.4
flask==2.3.2
routes==2.5.1
```

I modified *sendrequest.py*  as below:

```py
import  requests
import  json
url = "https://<mywebapp>.azurewebsites.net/test/"
payload = json.dumps({
"test": "Hello"
 })
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

[image]

*After debugging successfully, flask app is running on the below server http server.*

[image]

[image]